# Covolution (space) over compact Lie groups

Tags: operator-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group. Is there any way one can characterize the functions $\phi$ of the form $\phi=\psi\ast \psi^\ast$ in $C^\infty(G)$ where $\psi\in C^\infty(G)$? Here as usual $\psi^*(x)=\overline{\psi(x^{-1})}$. 
Another (perhaps easier) question is whether the above convolutions span the vector space $C^\infty(G)$ of smooth functions on $G$.

Both questions have puzzled me for a while, and I wonder if they are well known to the experts. (I have assumed that $G$ is compact for simplicity. Of course similar questions can be asked about compactly supported functions of any order over $G$.)

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that comes to my mind about this type of functions is as follows:

Given $f\in L^2(G)$, the function $f\ast \tilde{f}$, where $\tilde{f}(g)=\overline{f(g^{-1})}$, is a function of positive type associated with the left regular representation of $G$. For the involved terminology and definitions see Appendix C of the following book:

Kazhdan's Property (T)., by B. Bekka, P. de la Harpe, A. Valette.

It is available [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bachir.bekka/KazhdanTotal.pdf&ei=EMBxU5ntCu2X0AXw2oGQDg&usg=AFQjCNG0DQvAyJCK-uyhOVMDWFjIVe1HLg&sig2=iIXTZnWsVuoZk8UpdYlQxg&bvm=bv.66330100,d.d2k).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Regarding my second question, I think it is fairly easy to prove that the span of the functions of the form $\psi^\ast\ast\psi$ is **dense** in the entire $C^\infty(G)$. The argument goes as follows: any smooth $f$ can be uniformly approximated by $f\ast g$ which can be written in terms of $\psi^\ast\ast\psi$ functions by a polarization type argument. I don't know if the span can be proper or not. As for my first question, is there any handy sufficient condition which shows when a function $\phi$ equals $\psi^\ast\ast\psi$?